# How can I Switch to new Popup windows for e.g when clicking on sign up with google in playwright

Tags: javascript, jestjs, e2e-testing, webautomation, playwright

i'm trying to access new popup windows for google sign up in playwright and couldn't do it.

```
await page.waitForSelector(signUpWithGoogle, { state: 'visible' })
await page.focus(signUpWithGoogle)
await page.click(signUpWithGoogle)
await page.fill('//input[@type="email"]', email)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wait for the popup and then action on it:

```js
await page.waitForSelector(signUpWithGoogle, { state: 'visible' })
await page.focus(signUpWithGoogle)
const [popup] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForEvent('popup'),
  page.click(signUpWithGoogle),
]);

await popup.fill('//input[@type="email"]', email)
```